# Subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ such that their intersection is trivial.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $e_1, ..., e_n$ be a some fixed basis of $\mathbb R^n$ and $L \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a $k$-dimensional subspace. Prove that there is a subcollection $C$ of $n-k$ vectors from $e_1, ..., e_n$ such that $span(C) \cap L = \{0\}$.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us what have you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\dim L=k$ so it has a basis say $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k\}$.

Now using extension theorem and replacement theorem $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_k,e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_{n-k}\}$ is a basis of $V$.

Take $C=\{e_1,e_2,\ldots ,e_{n-k}\}$

Now let $x\in \text{span}C\cap L\implies x\in \text{span C}\implies x=\sum_{i=1}^{n-k} c_ie_i$

Also $x\in L\implies x=\sum_{i=1}^k d_ix_i$

Hence $0=x-x=\sum _{i=1}^{n-k} c_ie_i-\sum_{i=1}^k d_ix_i$
i.e. $0$ is expresssed in another way other than the trivial one.

But $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots ,x_k,e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_{n-k}\}$ is a basis of $V$ and  hence any element of $V $ is uniquely expressibe as a linear combination of its elements contradicting the earler result

Comment: Why downvotes?Explain